# Do I have to install drivers on each network card interface when using network teaming?

Tags: network-adapter

If I have network teaming enabled on a set of network interface cards/network adapters and I am required to install drivers, is it sufficient to install them on one network card or do I have to install them on each network card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want them all running the same driver assuming they are the same NICs.  Good news is that if all the NICs are the same and use the same driver, installing it once should update the driver for all.

Comment: What if they are different network adapters?

Comment: The the idea of using the same driver is a moot point.  I suspect teaming will get more complicated though

Comment: Yeah, you can't really use the same driver for different devices.  Maybe the drivers might come from the same PACKAGE, but...